# Why is the javascript "req" validator not working?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Here's the code:

```html
<script language="JavaScript">
  var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactform");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("name","required","Please provide your name");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("email","required","Please provide your email");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email",
  "Please enter a valid email address");
</script>

<form method="post" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php">
 <div class="row uniform 50%">
  <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
  </div>
  <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="Wemail" placeholder="Email" />
   </div>
 </div>
  <div class="row uniform 50%">
  <div class="12u">
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row uniform 50%">
  <div class="12u">
   <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="6">
      </textarea>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row uniform">
  <div class="12u">
   <ul class="actions align-center">
     <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's the console error:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: Validator is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 12,
  "colno": 27
}
```

The "email" validator functions as seen here:
[Screenshot of JS validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyw9N.png)

But, the "required" validators don't work. I tried "req" originally, but that didn't work either. I figured the duplicate id and name values could be at fault, but I changed them to no avail. I'm confused as to why the JS won't apply the required validator. What should I change to get this validation working?

Edit: I was using [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml) tutorial as a guide. The Validator object is in a downloadable .js file.
Fortunately, the comments and previous answers led me in the right direction. See the exact answer below.

Comment: Please tell us what library you're using for validation. There is no built-in JavaScript object `Validator`.

Comment: I wasn't worrying about libraries (I should have been) because I was following a tutorial. Thanks for making me pay closer attention to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the mistake I made was rather simple.
Rather than putting the gen_validatorv4.js script in the header of the html file, I placed it at the bottom of the `<body>` element, right before `</body>`.

For some reason (I'm not quite sure why - a comment explaining this would be awesome), placing the script in the header fixed the error.

Solution: Place the validator script in the header of the HTML, not at the end of the body.

Thanks, SO!

Comment: It's because everything which is in the header is compiled and executed before DOMReady event. For scripts in the <body> it's compiled later.

It's also a good practice to put most of the javascript (everything which is not crucial) to the end of the document. This way the user has the content faster (no need to download all the js before content is rendered).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but Validor doesn't seems to be a vanilla.js object.

If you try to use native html5 form validation you just need to add correct attributes to a form elements.

For email input it will be:
`<input type="email" required="required" .../>`

This will tell the browser to validate this field as an email and this field is mandatory.

Not all browser supports this (mostly some really old ones), but you need server validation anyway, so nowadays it might be a good idea to not implement anything custom in javascript.

If you need it though, find some javascript form validation libraries on github. There are plenty of them.

Or build one by yourself using `onchange` events or ```onsubmit`` for the overall form validation.

p.s. `<script language="JavaScript">` language is obsolete, type also.  is fine enough.

Comment: this was helpful!

Comment: @PujitM then please follow the SO etiquette and upvote the answer you find helpful or mark it as the "answer" if it answers your question.

Comment: I upvoted before I commented - I just don't have enough rep for it to show :(